# Sensitivity of topological field theories

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am struggling to find references or studies that explore the overall sensitivity of topological field theories as an invariant of smooth manifolds. There is the paper by [Davis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2358) that explores how unitary TQFTs cannot detect smooth structure in 4-manifolds, though this is a negative result for the efficacy of TQFTs as an invariant rather than a positive one. What properties of smooth manifolds are TQFTs known to be able to detect and distinguish? [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60550/usefulness-of-using-tqfts/) has already asked about topological properties but was asked 11 years ago and many of the answers are as old, so perhaps the literature has advanced since then. I will also expand that question's domain to include properties pertaining to smooth structure.

Comment: There's a [recent result of David Reutter](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.02288) saying that (once-)extended TFTs with values in 2Vec can't detect exotic smooth structures.

Comment: One dumb point, if you generalize enough, the identity TFT (with target the bordism category itself) obviously detects everything.